# How to properly code and interpret 2 categorical variables in a regression model?

Tags: regression

I'm working on a regression analysis, and I have both categorical and continuous independent variables in my dataset. Specifically, I'm interested in including race and gender as categorical variables in my regression model.

Consider:

```
Height ~ ß0 × age + ß1 × race + ß2 × gender.
```

Which of the following is correct interpretation:

```
1: Gender nested inside race:
      Race will be coded as 0 and 1, then:
      Gender = 0 and 1 (for race = 0)
      Gender = 0 & 1 (for Race = 1)

2: Gender and race not nested:
      Race will be coded as 0 and 1
      Gender will be coded as 0 and 1 (independent from race).
```

What will be the interpretation in the right case?

---

How will we interpret the interaction of race and gender in the following equation:

```
Height ~ ß0 × age + ß1 × race + ß2 × gender + ß3 × race * gender.
```